# @RequestMapping(value="/getRoles",method=RequestMethod.GET) public List<Roles> getRoles(){ return (List<Roles>) roleRepository.findAll(); }

Tags: assert, findall, test-coverage

```
 main method:
    @RequestMapping(value="/getAllUsers",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<UserRoleAssoc>  getAllUsers() {
            List<Users> userLst = (List<Users>) userRepository.findAll();
            final List<UserRoleAssoc>  userRoleAssociationList = new ArrayList<UserRoleAssoc>();
                for(Users users : userLst) {
                    List<UserRoleAssoc> userRoleAssoList = userRoleAssociationRepository.getRoleByuserId(users.getUserId());
                    if (userRoleAssoList != null) 
                    {
                        for (UserRoleAssoc userRoleList : userRoleAssoList) {
                            userRoleAssociationList.add(userRoleList);
                        }
                    }

                }
            return userRoleAssociationList;
        }
    test case:
/* start getAllUsers*/
    @Test
public void getAllUserstest() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(get(restEndPoints.GET_ALL_USERS.uri() + 987)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn().getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertNotNull(response.getContentAsString());}
```

i am unable to write test cases for these actually,GET and POst methods with findall is difficult to coverage

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Can you edit your question and explain the problem you are experiencing. Thanks.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/getAllUsers",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public List<UserRoleAssoc>  getAllUsers() {
  List<Users> userLst = (List<Users>) userRepository.findAll();
  final List<UserRoleAssoc>  userRoleAssociationList = new ArrayList<UserRoleAssoc>();
   for(Users users : userLst) {
    List<UserRoleAssoc> userRoleAssoList = userRoleAssociationRepository.getRoleByuserId(users.getUserId());
    if (userRoleAssoList != null) 
    {
     for (UserRoleAssoc userRoleList : userRoleAssoList) {
      userRoleAssociationList.add(userRoleList);
}}}return userRoleAssociationList;
}

Comment: this is my tets methosd fot main method below:please help to write test case for these 2 methods below: